# Pin corrupted after Motherboard change and cannot get to internet . Any fix

Tags: motherboard, pin

Just upgraded motherboard which I have done 3 times in the past without any issue.

Install motherboard, logged into Windows and then installed drivers and PIN was never an issue.

This time I did the install and booted Windows to get the next screen.

Login screen from OS disk 2:
[image: Login Screen from OS disk 2]

The only thing that I can do is click on "Set up my PIN" and if you look down bottom right we have the World icon so no internet.

If I had clicked it before taking the picture it would have shown just an icon for Ethernet 3 and nothing else.

Clicking takes you to a page that says you must have internet access to go any further so am completely stuck.

To try the route of installing a new version of windows I did have a raw Samsung 990 and installed windows onto that.

Did the get around the "Let's connect" not working by being able to install the driver from the ASUS Flash drive on dos by running a `.bat` file.

Was able to get online and complete the install.

Windows now running and now have a dual boot system, the other drive is now called X:

Found that windows had only installed the driver for my wireless adapter and not for the Intel I226-V Ethernet Adapter.

I had used the Windows 11 Installation Assistant that morning should have been the latest version.

Copied the driver folder over to the X: modified it to run on the X drive.

Ran it twice for the second run to say that it was overwriting existing code.

Checked    `C:\Windows\System32\DriverStore\FileRepository\e2fn.inf_amd64_19533fa54e0d0ffb` against its X: equivalent and found contents to be identical.

I there any way to fix the PIN in this situation without an internet connection?

Reboot system to get the X: disk to be the boot medium .

No change still no internet.

Cannot get either <kbd>Shift</kbd>-<kbd>F10</kbd> or <kbd>fn</kbd>-<kbd>Shift</kbd>-<kbd>F10</kbd> to work while this screen is up.

As this is a dual boot system, I setup a local account and then ran the install .bat file to update the contents of the X: OS disk and got the following results.

```
==============================================================
Scanning for new hardware.
Scanning completed.
Microsoft PnP Utility

Driver package uninstalled.
Failed to delete driver package: The specified file is not an installed OEM INF.
Updating drivers for PCI\VEN_8086&DEV_125C from X:\Newer_ASUS_DRV_LAN_Intel_I226_Cx_TP_W11_64_V2123_20221219R\e2fn.inf.
Drivers installed successfully.
Updating drivers for PCI\VEN_8086&DEV_125B from X:\Newer_ASUS_DRV_LAN_Intel_I226_Cx_TP_W11_64_V2123_20221219R\e2fn.inf.
devcon.exe failed.
Updating drivers for PCI\VEN_8086&DEV_15F2 from X:\Newer_ASUS_DRV_LAN_Intel_I226_Cx_TP_W11_64_V2123_20221219R\e2fn.inf.
devcon.exe failed.
Updating drivers for PCI\VEN_8086&DEV_15F3 from X:\Newer_ASUS_DRV_LAN_Intel_I226_Cx_TP_W11_64_V2123_20221219R\e2fn.inf.
devcon.exe failed.
Microsoft PnP Utility

Adding driver package:  e2fn.inf
Driver package added successfully. (Already exists in the system)
Published Name:         oem1.inf
Driver package is up-to-date on device: PCI\VEN_8086&DEV_125C&SUBSYS_88671043&REV_06\581122FFFFCB6FAB00

Total driver packages:  1
Added driver packages:  0
PS X:\Newer_ASUS_DRV_LAN_Intel_I226_Cx_TP_W11_64_V2123_20221219R>
======================================================
```

Do these results imply that the install worked or am I still missing something.

This was run from a local admin account called DavidCF.

Found out how to delete the NGC folder on the X: disk.
Rebooted and now just get the "Sign In" option everything else has been removed.

Clicked and got to the Microsoft window saying I need to be online to go any further.

So the driver is still not being seen.

Comment: You will need to enable and use the built-in Administrator account to install the adapters drivers.

Comment: Sorry but as I cannot get online to change my PIN I am not allowed to get Windows to use any account.

Comment: You’re not allowed to use the built-in Administrator account on your own machine? My suggestion stands, you will need to use the built-in account, to install the current driver for the Intel I226-V. You might have to use a secondary device since the driver is likely not operational without it. There is no way to bypass the message in your screenshot (other than using an Administrator account to solve the problem what likely is a corrupt NGC folder.